# Java threads: how do threads return values

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm a university student of Computer Science and I am familiar with threads in C.
However in Java the OOP makes Threads hard for me to understand.

I've written the following program and need to return values from the independent thread back to the main program.

The main program:

```
package main;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(fibonacci(400)); 
    }

    public static int fibonacci(int x) {
        Thread p1 = new Thread( new Fibonacci(x-1));
        Thread p2 = new Thread( new Fibonacci(x-2));
        p1.start();
        p2.start();

        int result = 0;
        // Here I need the returns of the threads
        // int result = thread_value1 + thread_value2;
        return result;
    }
}
```

The Fibonacci threads:

```
package main;

public class Fibonacci implements Runnable {

    int result;
    int x;

    public Fibonacci(int parameter) {
           x = parameter;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        result = fib(x);
    }

    public int fib(int x) {
        if(x == 1) return 1;
        if(x == 2) return 1;
        return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into `Callable` and `ExecutorService`.

Comment: or look at `Future` and `Task`.

Comment: You are pointing out one of the major problems of threads hacked into programming languages. Ada has a built in mechanism for doing just this.

Comment: One dubious way is to extend `Thread` instead of implementing `Runnable`.

Comment: I'll look into the suggested interfaces. I just looks like it'll complicate things even more, but at the moment it seems necessary. Thanks so far.

Comment: @user2418306, No need to extend Thread.  I'm assuming that you mean to extend it by adding a run() method and a field to hold the result.  If that's the case, then you can just as easily implement a Runnable class that has a field to hold the result....  Or a Runnable class with a constructor that accepts a container object where the thread should store the result, or... (probably several other ways to achieve the same end.)

Comment: Just a side note:  Your p2 thread computes f(x-2).  Your p1 thread will _also_ compute f(x-2) as an intermediate result while computing f(x-1).  In fact there isn't anything that will happen in the p2 thread that did not also happen in the p1 thread.  The _very best_ you can hope for from this program is that it won't take any longer than a single-threaded program that uses the same algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to save the results to a field in your `Fibonacci` objects and then read them from there. Note that since many threads will access this data, you need to synchronized access to these fields. In th e case of simple `int` values, adding the `volatile` modifier will be enough. It may also make the code clearer if you extend `Thread` instead of providing `Runnable` (but this is not neccessary). So your code could look something like this:

```
public class FibonacciThread extends Thread {
    public volatile int result;
    int x;

    public FibonacciThread(int parameter) {
       x = parameter;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        result = fib(x);
    }

    public int fib(int x) {
        if(x == 1) return 1;
        if(x == 2) return 1;
        return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2);
    }
}
```

In `main()` you then do something like:

```
FibonacciThread p1 = new FibonacciThread(x-1);
FibonacciThread p2 = new FibonacciThread(x-2);
p1.start();
p2.start();

p1.join();
p2.join();
int result = p1.result + p2.result;
```

I'm skipping getters/setters and any fancy design for brevity's sake.

The call to `Thread.join()` is needed in order to wait for the thread to finish so that you can be sure that the `result` field was calculated before you read its value.

Comment: I added the volatile variable to Main and now I get the following Massage for the 'int result = p1.result + p2.result;'   line:   'result cannot be resolved or is not a field'. Eclipse just does not find result

Comment: and I dont understand this Line: FibonacciThread p1 = new FibonacciThread(x-1), I changed it to Thread p1 = new Fibonacci(x-2);

Comment: The volatile variable should be in your thread class, FibonnacciThread, not in your main class. You also have to declare the threads as being of type FibonnacciThread since if you access them through a reference of type Thread, the newly added field will not be visible. I'll edit the answer to add some more detail.

Comment: Thanks, I still dont understand how I should create the threads for you solution to work.

Comment: Ok now it works, thanks a lot. But I think I have a lot more reading to do.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Sotirios Delimanolis in the comments, you can use `Callable` and `ExecutorService` for this, e.g. see [this example](http://www.journaldev.com/1090/java-callable-future-example)

Another alternative that may be overkill here, but that is especially useful if the threads are producing more than one value, is to use a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) or a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) to communicate between threads.  This is the basis behind libraries like [Akka](http://akka.io/).

```
public class Main {

    BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();

    public static int fibonacci(int x) {
        Thread p1 = new Thread( new Fibonacci(x-1, queue));
        Thread p2 = new Thread( new Fibonacci(x-2, queue));
        p1.start();
        p2.start();

        // wait for queues to have values in them, then remove the values
        int result = queue.take().intValue() + queue.take().intValue();
        return result;
    }
}

public class Fibonacci implements Runnable {

    int x;
    BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

    public Fibonacci(int parameter, BlockingQueue queueParam) {
           x = parameter;
           queue = queueParam;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // put output in queue
        queue.offer(new Integer(fib(x)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I just looked into Callable and I understand how it works. Going to write my first program with it, thanks.